# populate dropdownlist from hashtable

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

I'm trying to fill a dropdownlist from a Hashtable, the HashTable keys & values pulled from database,
  `private Hashtable myHashTable = new Hashtable();` 

using the following method:

```
void LoadmyHashTable()
{

    bussinessObject bs = new bussinessObject();
    myDataset ds = new myDataset();
    ds = bs.GetPosType(-1);

    int rowsCount = ds.myTable.Rows.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++)
    {
     myHashTable.Add(ds.myTable.Rows[i]["dTypeName"],ds.myTable.Rows[i]["dTypeId"] );

    }
}
```

then, after call the method in page load()
 and trying to fill the dropdownlist with the hashTable values:

```
        myDropdownlist.DataSource = myHashTable;
        myDropdownlist.DataTextField = "key";
        myDropdownlist.DataValueField = "value";
        myDropdownlist.DataBind();
```

The problem my dropdownlist appear with empty!
Thanks in advance.

 ASP.NET,C#

Comment: Any reason you're still using non-generic collections? Are you actually using .NET 1.1 for some reason?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a hashtable be bound to a drop down list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298926/how-can-a-hashtable-be-bound-to-a-drop-down-list)

Comment: @JonSkeet, thank you.. I appreciate if you provide the best solution.

Comment: @Salahaldin: Well it's hard to answer a question without knowing the requirements. Do you actually require it to work with .NET 1.1? I can't think of any other reason you'd want to use Hashtable, but it obviously limits the answers.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Actually No, I'm working with .NET 3.5  .

Comment: @Salahaldin: Okay, so start using generic collections for one thing. Now, is there any reason you're creating a hashtable/dictionary in the first place? Do you need to look up the keys later on? If not, why don't you just bind to the table itself, using `dTypeName` and `dTypeId` as the text and value fields?

Comment: @JonSkeet ,I'm using the dropdown ddl within a gridview, So when I bind it, it callback the db many time as numbers of rows. I don't mind to use another solution.:-)

Comment: As Jon said it would be good idea not to use Hashtable rather generic list List<Type> and bind it with ddl. You can get any values on server side

Answer (score 1):

I have modify code as below please try it.

```
void LoadmyHashTable()
{

    bussinessObject bs = new bussinessObject();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds = bs.GetPosType(-1);      
    if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count-1; i++)
        {
            myHashTable.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["dTypeId"], ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["dTypeName"]);

        }
    }

}
```

use code for page load as below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadmyHashTable();
        if (myHashTable.Count > 0)
        {
            myDropdownlist.DataSource = myHashTable;
            myDropdownlist.DataTextField = "Value";
            myDropdownlist.DataValueField = "Key";
            myDropdownlist.DataBind();

        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will helps you...happy coding...

Comment: did u get check that if your hashtable have the items ??

Comment: ,yes it's. But the dropdownlist it hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` values need to each correspond to a property in the binding source. Your code assumes a collection of objects that have at minimum a property named "key" and another named "value". Since this is not true, no items get bound.

**EDIT:** This code hasn't been tested *at all*, but you should be able to use LINQ to project your dataset into an anonymous collection:

```
var myHashTable = ds.myTable.Rows.Select( row => new { key = row["dTypeName"], value = row["dTypeId"] } );
```

Then the binding you are using should work.